# Simple WYSYWYG editor (clicking a button unselects what was selected)

Tags: javascript

```
function getSelectionText() {
    let text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}


jQuery("#h").click(function() {
    let selection = getSelectionText();
    selection = "<p class='n-h8'>" + selection + "</p>"
});

<p>
        <span id="h" class="button tag">H</span>
</p>

<textarea></textarea>
```

I'm trying to create some kind of Wysywyg editor. I want to input some text into textarea. Then select some part of it with my mouse. Then click on "h" button.

And the selected text will be wrapped in p tag

Example: if I have selected

> **What is Lorem Ipsum?**

Then after clicking "H" button I  will get:

```
<p class='n-h8'>What is Lorem Ipsum?</p>
```

Well, I failed even to get the selected text. As soon as I click my button, the text is no longer selected as I have clicked on the button hence no text is selected any more.

How can WYSYWYG buttons be organised using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    let selection = '';
    // function getSelectionText() {
    //     let text = "";
    //     if (window.getSelection) {
    //         text = window.getSelection().toString();
    //     } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    //         text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    //     }
    //     return text;
    // }


    $("#h").click(function () {
        this.innerHTML = selection;
    });

    function onMouseUp(e) {
        const activeTextarea = document.activeElement;
        selection = activeTextarea.value.substring(
            activeTextarea.selectionStart, activeTextarea.selectionEnd
        );
    }

    const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
    textarea.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
</head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.js" integrity="sha256-a9jBBRygX1Bh5lt8GZjXDzyOB+bWve9EiO7tROUtj/E="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
    <p id="text-container">
        <span id="h" class="button tag">H</span>
    </p>

    <textarea></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

The issue may be browser-specific. For details and resolution, please refer to [W3C](https://w3c.github.io/selection-api/#dom-window-getselection) or [MDN documentation](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection).
[image]

Comment: This is all good. But somehow WYSYWYG editors are programmed. Stackoverflow is an example. Could you help me understand how not to loose selection when I click on the button.

Comment: @TrtsI attach a 'mouseup' event listener to the textarea and store the selection in the global variable 'selection' to meet your needs.